# Vertically align a row from bootstrap inside a div width issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width, vertical-alignment

Trying to center a bootstrap row and it's contents inside a div. The code is below:

HTML:

```
<div class="horizontal-layout">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="packet-icon">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/Icons/ic_coversheet_blue.png" style="height:100px; width:100px; cursor:pointer;">
            <h4>Add</h4>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="packet-icon">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/Icons/ic_onepager_pink.png" style="height:100px; width:100px;cursor:pointer ">
            <h4>Add</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="packet-icon">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/Icons/ic_user_profile_green.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;cursor:pointer ">
            <h4>Add</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="packet-icon">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/Icons/ic_create_packet.png" style="height:100px; width:100px;cursor:pointer">
            <h4>View</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .horizontal-layout {
    /*background-color: blue;*/
    min-height: 700px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #F26631;
    padding: 30px;
}

.packet-icon {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #F26631;
    min-height: 140px;
    min-width: 140px;
}
```

RESULT:

[image]

But When I go and make changes to parent div(horizontal-layout) be displayed flex and the child div to align-middle, my width of row changes.

After Css Change:

```
.horizontal-layout {
    /*background-color: blue;*/
    min-height: 700px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #F26631;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}

    .horizontal-layout > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Can anyone fix the row with issue?

Comment: have you tried `margin: 0 auto;` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. That didn't work either.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `div` was `display: block`, so that the width was automatically 100%.

Specifying `.horizontal-layout > div` to `display: inline-block` changed that behavior, so if you want to keep that, you have to set width manually:

```
.horizontal-layout > div {
    ...
    width: 100%;
}
```